# Using websockets/Server sent events with Angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I was trying to use angular dart with websockets/server sent events and could not find any documentation/examples (there are some for angularJS but that seems very different for such things). A few things I tried also did not work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is one version of what I tried and the error:

```dart
@NgController (
    selector: "ACdistribution",
    publishAs : "dstbn")
class ACDstbnController{
  List <WtdPres> distbn;

  void updateDstbn(List<WtdPres> newdstbn){
    distbn = newdstbn;
  }


  final dstbnsrc = new EventSource("../dstbns")
        ..onMessage.listen((event){
    List wps = JSON.decode(event.data);
    List <WtdPres> newdistbn = wps.map((wp) => new WtdPres.fromJson(wp));
    updateDstbn(newdistbn);
      });

}
```

The error I got in pub build was:

```dart
web/provingground.dart:55:5:
'updateDstbn' is only available in instance methods.
    updateDstbn(newdistbn);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information what you try to accomplish? Some code that shows what you tried and what didn't work out as you wished would be great.

Comment: I have a dynamical system running on the server (in scala/play) generating certain probability distributions. I want to send info to the front end periodically, which should get updated. This works via server sent events with dom manipulation (I did this in another application). But within an angular controller, I get various errors depending on which way I try to do things.

Comment: I find it rather hard to discuss approaches on such a generic level. Could you just drop a few lines of code, for example of your controller. I can't imagine what a problem you could have. Maybe it is about async programming in general? Please add additional info to your question not as comments (code in comments is unreadable). Then add a short comment so I get notified about the update.

Comment: I have put in some code, and the error message for pub build.

Comment: Great! I guess you got notified about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limitations on what you can do on initializers for final fields.

Can you try to put this code inside the constructor

```dart
var dstbnsrc;

ACDstbnController() {
  dstbnsrc = new EventSource("../dstbns")
        ..onMessage.listen((event){
    List wps = JSON.decode(event.data);
    List <WtdPres> newdistbn = wps.map((wp) => new WtdPres.fromJson(wp));
    updateDstbn(newdistbn);
      });
}
```

Comment: I actually tried with var first, then changed that to final. I get the same error in both cases.

Comment: And have you tried to put the initialization code inside the constructor (or some method). Your code doesn't look wrong, but I haven't done it this way myself yet. I changed it to var because you can't initialize a final field from the constructor body.

Comment: Thanks. I put it in a constructor and it built.

Comment: Great! Can you please accept the answer when it solved your problem by clicking the check mark below the up/down-vote-buttons. Thanks!